# Write response to HTTP GET request, Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, get, response

I have controller that is working with incoming GET requests.

GET request:

```
http://localhost:3000/sms/receive?sms-id=7bb28e244189f2cf36cbebb9d1d4d02001da53ab&operator-%20id=1&from=37126300682&to=371144&text=IL3+68975&charged=1
```

In both cases I need to respond  GET request with 2 variables **price** and **answer**.

I have PHP example that works:

```
if (empty($login)){ // Ja abonents nav noradijis lietotajvardu (login), no vina netiek nonemta nauda un tiek nosutita kludas SMS
    $price = 0.10;
    $answer = "Atvainojiet, Jus neesat noradijusi lietotajvardu (login)SMS teksta. Uzmanigi parbaudiet    nosutito tekstu!";
}else{ // Ja lietotajvards (login) noradits, abonents tiek tarificets
    $price = 1.00;
    $answer = "Paldies, ".$login."! Jusu SMS pienemta. Pakalpojuma cena ".$price.". Pakalpojums tiks piedavats pec apmaksas apstiprinajuma";
}
header("x-esteria-price: ".sprintf("%.2f", $price));
echo $answer;
exit();
```

But I can't understand how to do the same In Rails 4.
I tried like this so far:

Controller:

```
if @billing.present? && @advertisement.present?
     params[:answer] = "Paldies #{@advertisement.identifier} Jusu SMS pienemta. Pakalpojuma cena . Pakalpojums tiks piedavats pec apmaksas apstiprinajuma"
     params[:price] = @billing.price
     request.headers["x-esteria-price: 0.95"] 

 else
     params[:answer] = "Atvainojiet, Jus neesat noradijusi lietotajvardu (login)SMS teksta. Uzmanigi parbaudiet  nosutito tekstu!"
     params[:price] = 0.10 #???         
     request.headers["x-esteria-price: 0.10"]  
  end
```

When I execute this code there is no error message shown.

Any tips ? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: So your problem is that you're *not* getting an error?

Comment: @RobertHarvey I don't know how to check if the response is succesfull or not. And I don't know if I am doing it in right way..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line

```
request.headers["x-esteria-price: 0.10"]
```

is editing the header of the request not the response. Switch to request to response.

```
response.headers["x-esteria-price: 0.10"]
```

Comment: Thanks, how can I check these responses if I am working on my locale machine?

Comment: Use [cURL](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/httpscripting.html) to issue a get request to localhost and look at the headers.